# positioning data on your webpage pulled from a mysql database

Tags: php

I am trying to position the data pulled from my mysql database using the following php code on my webpage;

```
<?php
    require "connect.php";
    $query =  "select * from item LIMIT 0, 1";
    $result = @mysql_query($query, $connection) 
    or die ("Unable to perform query<br>$query");
?>

<?php
while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?

//call each item from the database, and nest in div or html table

<?=$row['item']?>
<?=$row['description']?>
<?=$row['brand']?>
```

When I view the webpage it creates the row for each item however each field is empty?

The conection to the database is fine as I ran another piece of code which simply displayed all the info in 1 block. However this is not what I want I want to be able to position each item where I want it on the site.

I wrote this when I had php version 4.1 running on IIS I am now running the latest version of php 5 and after doing some reading it says there are chnages in the syntax including global variables disabled by default so not sure if this is the issue?

Comment: What do you see if you print_r($row) ? Which db are you using?

Comment: Are short tags enabled on the new version of PHP? They're somewhat deprecated "because not everyone has them enabled so your code won't be portable"

Comment: I used <?=$print_r($item)?> to call the item field from the database and still nothing is displayed?

Comment: For you it's not `print_r($item)` but `print_r($row)` in while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php echo $row['item'] ?>
<?php echo $row['description'] ?>
<?php echo $row['brand'] ?>
```

I believe the `<?= ?>` syntax is normally disabled by default.

The following will also show a dump of you $row array, so you can make sure that it actually contains data

```
<?php print_r($row); ?>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sorttag maybe no enabled, try :

```
<?php echo $row['item']; ?>
<?php echo $row['description']; ?>
<?php echo $row['brand']; ?>
```

Comment: <? ?> is discouraged, use <?php ?> instead.